# In CSS, how do I make the text not go on a 2nd line?

Tags: css, templates

Suppose I have text inside a div right now. When I resize my browser to make it really small, the text goes on a 2nd line instead of making the scroll bar.

Instead, I would like to keep the text all on one line and just have a horizontal scroll bar. How can I do this? WIth overflow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use white-space:

```
#myDiv { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Or:

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap;">Long text that I do not want wrapped</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off automatic wrapping using the white-space property, like this:

```
#theDiv { white-space: nowrap }
```